# byebug and ruby 2.2.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pry, byebug

When trying to use byebug for the first time with ruby 2.2.3 I get

```
NameError:
      undefined local variable or method `byebug'
```

I'm confused, here's are some diagnostics:

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]

cat Gemfile | grep bye
gem 'byebug'

gem list | grep bye
byebug (8.2.1, 8.2.0)

#the command I'm using to run my ruby code is
rspec *spec.rb --tag focus
#also tried prepending bundle exec
```

Comment: To facilitate debugging I have a require 'byebug' in my rspec_helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out. I needed this line:

```
require 'byebug'; byebug;
```

in my ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

did you run `bundle install` on your app (assuming this is in the context of a rails app given that you're using Gemfiles)?

Edit: you figured it out, I see :D I was going to suggest requiring the library next but I see that I didn't need to.